# VB6 PictureBox SavePicture - save picture as png?

Tags: vb6, png, picturebox

With VB6 PictureBox, how do I save to the png format?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  The VB6 PictureBox only supports Bitmap, icon, metafile, GIF, and JPEG image types.  You'll need to use something else if you wish to work with PNG files.  Perhaps the [Windows Image Acquisition Automation Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29) would be of use to you.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the cPNGWriter.cls file in LaVolpe's 32bpp Suite:

http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=67466&lngWId=1

As stated in the class comments, it does require zlib.

Answer (score -1):

You can [write a DLL to save in PNG in VB.Net and then call from VB6](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_vb6_net_save_image.html). From VB6 graphics guru Rod Stephens

Comment: True, but that sorta defeats the purpose of using VB6 over .NET when you have to check for/install the .NET framework with your app.

Comment: @Joe I see your point, but you might have an existing VB6 app that you wish to extend to support PNG.

Answer (score -1):

The **best** and **easiest** way - use the ***GDIPlus*** Library.
If you don't know how, google it