# How to create a PNG file in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB6 PictureBox SavePicture - save picture as png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754233/vb6-picturebox-savepicture-save-picture-as-png)

How do I create a PNG file in Visual Basic 6.5 with a height of 10 and a width of 6?

What is the header file inclusion to draw an png file?

Comment: See if this works for you http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/vbMedia/Using_GDI_Plus/Reading_and_Writing_JPG__PNG__TIF_and_GIF_Files/article.asp

Comment: "Create" as in "write a blank (all black?) PNG file to disk" or what?  Then you say "draw."  What do you really mean?

Comment: yaa thats my next question? how to enable only a particular pixel say i want to enable (2,4)th position and i want to disable the (3,4)th pixel? how to do it.?

Comment: @danison: That should be posted as a different question, once you've created a picture in VB6 (Using a DIB, PictureBox, etc), then this function will just save it as PNG for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen a module before that uses GDI+ to convert BMP to PNG

Here's that module as a .bas file:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type
Private Type GdiplusStartupInput
    GdiplusVersion As Long
    DebugEventCallback As Long
    SuppressBackgroundThread As Long
    SuppressExternalCodecs As Long
End Type
Private Type EncoderParameter
    GUID As GUID
    NumberOfValues As Long
    type As Long
    Value As Long
End Type
Private Type EncoderParameters
    count As Long
    Parameter As EncoderParameter
End Type

Private Declare Function GdiplusStartup Lib "GDIPlus" (token As Long, inputbuf As GdiplusStartupInput, Optional ByVal outputbuf As Long = 0) As Long
Private Declare Function GdiplusShutdown Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal token As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal hbm As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, BITMAP As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GdipDisposeImage Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal Image As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GdipSaveImageToFile Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal Image As Long, ByVal FileName As Long, clsidEncoder As GUID, encoderParams As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32" (ByVal Str As Long, id As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Dest As Any, Src As Any, ByVal cb As Long) As Long

Public Sub SavePic(ByVal pict As StdPicture, ByVal FileName As String, PicType As String, _
    Optional ByVal Quality As Byte = 80, _
    Optional ByVal TIFF_ColorDepth As Long = 24, _
    Optional ByVal TIFF_Compression As Long = 6)
    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    Dim tSI As GdiplusStartupInput
    Dim lRes As Long
    Dim lGDIP As Long
    Dim lBitmap As Long
    Dim aEncParams() As Byte
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle:
    tSI.GdiplusVersion = 1
    lRes = GdiplusStartup(lGDIP, tSI)
    If lRes = 0 Then
        lRes = GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(pict.Handle, 0, lBitmap)
        If lRes = 0 Then
            Dim tJpgEncoder As GUID
            Dim tParams As EncoderParameters
            Select Case PicType
            Case ".jpg"
                CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{557CF401-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E}"), tJpgEncoder
                tParams.count = 1
                With tParams.Parameter
                    CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{1D5BE4B5-FA4A-452D-9CDD-5DB35105E7EB}"), .GUID
                    .NumberOfValues = 1
                    .type = 4
                    .Value = VarPtr(Quality)
                End With
                ReDim aEncParams(1 To Len(tParams))
                Call CopyMemory(aEncParams(1), tParams, Len(tParams))
            Case ".png"
                CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{557CF406-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E}"), tJpgEncoder
                ReDim aEncParams(1 To Len(tParams))
            Case ".gif"
                CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{557CF402-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E}"), tJpgEncoder
                ReDim aEncParams(1 To Len(tParams))
            Case ".tiff"
                CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{557CF405-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E}"), tJpgEncoder
                tParams.count = 2
                ReDim aEncParams(1 To Len(tParams) + Len(tParams.Parameter))
                With tParams.Parameter
                    .NumberOfValues = 1
                    .type = 4
                    CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{E09D739D-CCD4-44EE-8EBA-3FBF8BE4FC58}"), .GUID
                    .Value = VarPtr(TIFF_Compression)
                End With
                Call CopyMemory(aEncParams(1), tParams, Len(tParams))
                With tParams.Parameter
                    .NumberOfValues = 1
                    .type = 4
                    CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{66087055-AD66-4C7C-9A18-38A2310B8337}"), .GUID
                    .Value = VarPtr(TIFF_ColorDepth)
                End With
                Call CopyMemory(aEncParams(Len(tParams) + 1), tParams.Parameter, Len(tParams.Parameter))
            Case ".bmp"
                SavePicture pict, FileName
                Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
                Exit Sub
            End Select
            lRes = GdipSaveImageToFile(lBitmap, StrPtr(FileName), tJpgEncoder, aEncParams(1))
            GdipDisposeImage lBitmap
        End If
        GdiplusShutdown lGDIP
    End If
    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
    Erase aEncParams
    Exit Sub
  ErrHandle:
    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
    MsgBox "Error" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error No. " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & " Error .Description:  " & Err.Description, vbInformation Or vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

how to invoke:

```
SavePic(ByVal pict As StdPicture, ByVal FileName As String, PicType As String, _
    Optional ByVal Quality As Byte = 80, _
    Optional ByVal TIFF_ColorDepth As Long = 24, _
    Optional ByVal TIFF_Compression As Long = 6)

StdPicture -  A picture handle, or a picture box
FileName - The file name to save
PicType - File format to save, available formats: .jpg, .png, .gif, .tiff, .bmp
Quality - Picture quality, default is 80%
```

example:

```
SavePic Picture1.Image, "C:\Test.png", ".png"
```

Comment: i can use this code then GDI+ will convert from bitmapp to png right? i dont know what is this .bas file?what it will do?

Comment: @danison: What will it do? It converts a VB picture to a PNG (amongst others) file, as you asked for. The last example shows how. Admittedly, the samples could do with commenting.

Comment: This will not work I just tested.. If you run it as `SavePic Picture1, "C:\Test.png", ".png"` the `pict.Handle` will always return 0, which isn't right. All I did was create a new `PictureBox` set `AutoRedraw` to `True` and used `SetPixel` on it. It seems `StdPicture` isn't a `PictureBox`. Anyways I fixed it the problem is with your code. It's suppose to be `SavePic, Picture1.Image, "C:\Test.png", ".png"`

Answer (score 1):

VB6 and VBA (the VB6.5 you're using) do not natively support PNGs. You will need to use GDI+ (as Mark linked to), WIA or another external/3rd party library.

Comment: Actually they do since WIA 2.0 came along.  Yes, it's a helper library but it's been standard for a decade and shipped in Windows since Vista came out.

Comment: That's still not native to VB, and that was implied by "3rd party libraries". Changed to "external" to clarify.

Comment: That's a bit like saying the Script Control or ADO or MSXML or ... are not native.  They're all parts of the VB6 ecosystem, and in this case WIA was specially targeted as an addition to support VB6 and scripting.  The main point is that you can use WIA for PNG support.

Comment: They aren't "native VB6". Yes, you can use them from VB6, but they aren't "part of VB", they're part of Windows or the data access tools. I wasn't saying you can't do it from VB, you just need to use an external library like GDI+ or WIA.

Comment: With WIA  i THINK THAT A MEMORY BITMAP  has to be saved as a bitmap file then compress  ( a  2500 KB BMP is  if B&W text is 35 KB JPG.. Since I can not bitblt memory bit maps to shapes on a sheet  (that stay there )  . but shapes can load their  pictures  and JPG  much better.... Thanks for your excellent efforts.  Am trying memory bitmaps for their speed in manipulating text like a page of mixing 14X14 and 14 X12 and 14X8 fonts to pack an format info to small A6 booklets